# CURL is not returning correct response when json data is passed through variable

Tags: php-curl, jdoodle

`$data` is the variable holding json string `{"clientId":"MyClientID","clientSecret":"MyClientSecret","script":"<?php\n echo \"Welcome to GLB Coding Club\";\n?>\n","stdin":"","language":"php","versionIndex":"2"}`.

as you can see in the first line below. I have encoded array into json using `json_encode()`

```
$data = json_encode(array("clientId"=>"MyClientID","clientSecret"=>"MyClientSecret","script"=> $this->input->post("script",true),"stdin"=>$this->input->post("stdin",true),"language"=>$this->input->post("language",true),"versionIndex"=>$this->input->post("versionIndex",true)));

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("cache-control: no-cache","content-type: application/json"),
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } 
        else {
            echo $response;
        }
```

jdoodle is not returning correct `$response` instead returning the statements that were given to execute. But if I replace `$data` by actual json string `{"clientId":"MyClientID","clientSecret":"MyClientSecret","script":"<?php\n echo \"Welcome to GLB Coding Club\";\n?>\n","stdin":"","language":"php","versionIndex":"2"}` at `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data` then jdoodle is returning correct `$response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply edited `$this->input->post("script",true)` to `html_entity_decode($this->input->post("script",true))`.

Answer (score 0):

Then, simply

```
json_encode(array("clientId"=>"MyClientID","clientSecret"=>"MyClientSecret","script"=> $this->input->post("script",true),"stdin"=>$this->input->post("stdin",true),"language"=>$this->input->post("language",true),"versionIndex"=>$this->input->post("versionIndex",true)))
```

is not producing the `$data` string that you expect and that gives correct response:

```
'{"clientId":"MyClientID","clientSecret":"MyClientSecret","script":"<?php\n echo \"Welcome to GLB Coding Club\";\n?>\n","stdin":"","language":"php","versionIndex":"2"}'
```

Just

```
echo $data;
exit(0);
```

after the first line and check what is wrong when forming the `$data` string

Comment: I copied the string by `echo $data`.